# How can I open a WPF window in a Progress openedge ABL dialog?

Tags: wpf, progress-4gl, openedge

Is there an example to open WPF window in a Progress openedge ABL dialog?

Comment: In a dialog (embedded) or from a dialog?

Comment: Thank you @MikeFechner for your response.
I mean how to launch a WPF window from progress openedge program and how to exchange parameters between openedge ABL and c# ?
Actually, I need to open a web browser embedded in WPF window from progress openedge program. When I click the button save (in wpf window) I need to launch an openedge script to read and save JSON file in the progress database .

Comment: I've already tried OCX. there was a problem with jquery on Microsoft Web Browser

Comment: So, actually your question is something different from what you have posted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The use of WPF is officially not supported by Progress Software. However most things work - if you keep your fingers from multi-threading features (or know exactly what you are doing there).

I strongly suggest you read through the GUI for .NET documentation here: https://community.progress.com/community_groups/openedge_general/w/openedgegeneral/2743.openedge-11-6-product-documentation

You should be able to launch a (non blocking) WPF window from ABL code.

You cannot embed WPF elements into ABL widgets.

You can embed ABL widgets into a WinForms Form and then add an ElementHost Control to the Form on top of the WindowContainer that hosts your ABL Window (won't work with a Dialog frame though).

Is this worth the effort? I doubt it! It's rather go with a more modern WinForms browser control, this might get you started: https://thechriskent.com/2014/08/18/embedded-chromium-in-winforms/

Answer (score 0):

This is very possible by creating a Winform and then calling the WPF application from there all within a Progress session. We have done this within an MDI interface that is running both Progress ABL and WPF in the same Session.